# How to create entities on another site using the Web Services Client module

Tags: 7, rules, services

I have installed the [Web Services Client module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient), together with the Drupal Services module and Rules, in order to create, edit and delete entities on a remote Drupal site.

The remote Drupal site has a REST service that allows all CRUD operations on entities (products) using the [Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services).

I aim to create update delete remote entities using the Web Services Client module, but have a hard time understanding how the "Service Description" (admin/config/services/wsclient) should be created to accomplish that.

What are the steps to create such Service Description using REST services, and the corresponding Rules?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: All you need to configure only [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module. It provides CRUD operation with rules support.

Comment: @vgoradiya I don't see how to do that without creating a custom module. Please explain?